# django cannot get request from hyperlink

Tags: django, url, get

I have made a hyperlink like this

```
<a href="{% url "csv_download" %}?format="csv"">Download CSV</a>
```

and my url is

```
url(r'^download/(?P<format>)',SingleNewsView.as_view(), name="csv_download")
```

In my view i have get method that get the format and if there is format=csv I want to do query. I dont know how to get this format. When I run the above script it gives get() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given). Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL pattern is looking for a *named* parameter, but you're actually passing it a *querystring* parameter.

If you want the pattern to be:

```
/download/csv/
```

Then you'll need to change your call to `url` to:

```
<a href="{% url "csv_download" "csv" %}">Download CSV</a>
```

If you want to get the value from the querystring instead, you'l need to change your URL pattern to:

```
url(r'^download/$',SingleNewsView.as_view(), name="csv_download")
```

and then you can pick up the "format" parameter using:

```
format = request.GET.get('format')
```

In either case, you're also missing the pattern terminator, "/$", which should be:

```
url(r'^download/(?P<format>)/$',SingleNewsView.as_view(), name="csv_download")
```

Comment: "csv" is the value of `format` if you're using the named parameter method. Your view would need to accept a keyword argument named "format": `def my_view(request, format):`

Comment: I also have a form in that view and I am getting their value without any prob. I used def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs). I am not able to get format. I used the hyperlink as  <a href="{% url "csv_download" format="csv" %}">Download CSV</a> and url as url(r'^download/(?P<format>)/$',SingleNewsView.as_view(), name="csv_download"). What am I doing wrong. I tried request.GET.get("format")

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: {% url 'csv_download' format='csv'%} or {% url 'csv_download' 'csv' %}

Comment: I tried this <a href="{% url "csv_download" format="csv" %}">Download CSV</a> but it shows the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this  {% url 'csv_download' csv %} and add +W after format

Comment: This would assume that `csv` is a variable in the view context.